# ParseInt method returns NaN when parsing a Negative Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, parseint

What I am trying to achieve is to parse a String (-1800000) from a query param from my GET method. But when I printed the result value it returns NaN.

This is the end point of the call :

calendar?day=1555131600000?offset=-18000000

On the server side am parsing the offset data like this:

```
const offsetInt = parseInt(req.query.offset)
```

But when I printed in the console it returns NaN

```
Console.log(offsetInt)
```

I have tried using

```
 parseInt(req.query.offset,10) 

 parseInt(req.query.offset).valueOf())
```

but it keeps returning NaN.

I want to use the offsetInt variable to add/reduce milliseconds to my UTC Datetime in order to get the initial hour of a date.

```
const start = moment(day)
    .startOf('day')
    .add(offsetInt,'milliseconds')
    .valueOf();
```

Comment: I think you should try `console.log(req.query.offset)` first and make sure that you have the value you think you have.

Comment: `calendar?day=1555131600000?offset=-18000000` error lies here, should be `calendar?day=1555131600000&offset=-18000000`

Comment: calendar?day=1555131600000?offset=-18000000,  you have two ? in your query string it should be calendar?day=1555131600000&offset=-18000000

Comment: Omg what a stupid mistake I made. Now it works perfectly!! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint & query strings are not really correct, so you have :

```
calendar?day=1555131600000?offset=-18000000
```

basically you only have access to value of this parameter :

```
day=1555131600000
```

you need to separate each parameter with `&` so then you can have access to `offset` value :

```
calendar?day=1555131600000&offset=-18000000
```